# for loop missing initialization

Tags: c

I've seen

```
for(;;)
```

and

```
for ( ; *s != '\0'; s++)
```

Why is it blank like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `for` statement works like:

`for (initialization; test-condition; update)`

And any or all of those three can be omitted (left blank). So:

- `for (;;)` is an infinite loop<sup>1</sup> equivalent to `while (true)` because there is no test condition. In fact, `for (int i=0; ;i++)` would also be an infinite loop<sup>1</sup>.
- `for ( ; *s != '\0'; s++)` is a loop with no initialization. `s` will point to the beginning of (probably) a string and is incremented until it reaches the null character `'\0'` denoting end-of-string. This essentially means loop through all characters of the string `s`

<sup>1</sup> The loop will still be interrupted if there's a `break` statement in the loop body, or a call to `exit()`, etc...

Comment: `\0` is the `NUL` character.`NUL` and `NULL` are different.

Comment: @Prasoon Some people (like myself) just call it the [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

Answer (score 7):

It is "blank like that" because the author of the code left it blank. The author did not want/need to do anything in the corresponding section of `for` statement, so it was left blank.

`for (;;)` is a statement that iterates indefinitely (unless it is interrupted from inside cycle body).

`for ( ; *s != '\0'; s++)` is a statement that does not need an initialization section, since everything necessary (like the initial value of `s`) was already initialized before that `for` statement.

Answer (score 5):

`for(;;)` is an infinite loop. It is effectively the exact same as `while (true)`.

The reason this works is because when the middle condition in a `for` loop is empty, it is interpreted as always being true.

`for ( ; *s != '\0'; s++)` is used for reading strings character-by-character. This approach works because every C string ends with a null character (`\0`).

Answer (score 2):

The parts that are blank essentially do nothing. So `for (;;)` creates an infinite loop that does nothing at all, and never exits because there is no condition in the loop. Your second example:

```
for ( ; *s != '\0'; s++)
```

is just a normal loop without any initialization expression. This relies on the fact that `s` already has an initial value and just loops until it reaches the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

`while(1)` and `while(true)` are the same as `for(;;)`

Answer (score 1):

it means do forever

for (initial condition; increment; end condition); You can omit any of these

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

> The three control expressions,
>   separated by semicolons here, are from
>   left to right the initializer
>   expression, the loop test expression,
>   and the counting expression. The
>   initializer is evaluated exactly once
>   right at the start of the loop. The
>   loop test expression is evaluated at
>   the beginning of each iteration
>   through the loop, and determines when
>   the loop should exit. Finally, the
>   counting expression is evaluated at
>   the end of each loop iteration - even
>   if continue is called - and is usually
>   responsible for altering the loop
>   variable.
>
> In most languages which provide this
>   type of for loop, each of the three
>   control loop expressions is optional.
>   When omitted the loop test expression
>   is taken to always be true, while the
>   initializer and counting expressions
>   are treated as no-ops when omitted.
>   The semicolons in the syntax are
>   sufficient to indicate the omission of
>   one of the expressions.