# New form of for loop in C language?

Tags: c, for-loop

Not long ago, I stumbled across a very interesting innovation in a `for` loop (or maybe it is nothing new but I've been living in a cave?). Please take a look and explain to me why the initialize gap is empty? Of course, that's the part of the program which works. I would grateful for any revelation:)

```
void rzad_zn(char ch, int i, int j)
{
    int pom;
    pom = i;
    for(; i<=j; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(; pom<=j; pom++)
    {
        printf("%c ", ch);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Ancient, not new. That was possible in previous century C already. Leaving out the part before the first `;`. It is the "initialiser gap empty", exactly. Nothing else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for loop missing initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792183/for-loop-missing-initialization)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot and sorry for my knowledge gap:(

Comment: You can use `for ( ; ; )` too — it has an implicit 'true' condition, no initialization and no re-initialization.  Each of the components of the `for` loop is optional; the two semicolons are all that are mandatory.

Comment: Fyi, all three parts of a for-loop are optional. `for(;cond;)` is effectively a while-loop. `for(;;++pom)` would be an infinite loop with increment. `for(;;)` is effectively `while(1)`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop has three components, *all* of which are optional, as in this is a valid loop as well:

```
for (;;) { }
```

Though it is an infinite loop unless something calls `break`.

Any combination of arguments may be used, even compound ones like:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < j; ++i) { ... }
```

Where you can declare multiple variables, or use the comma operator in the other parts to join together several operations if necessary.

Comment: Awesome! Good to know, im just beggining

Comment: `for (;;) ;` saves a character (and a space) :)

Comment: @pmg Personal preference at that point. Some prefer `{ }` to make it clear it's intentional and not an accident, and also to avoid situations where the subsequent line is indented as if it's visually part of the loop but is actually not.

Comment: `int i = 0, j = 0` does not have a comma operator. It is a declaration with two *init-declarators*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point. I was trying to think of an example for the second part, but got lazy, so the phrasing is wrong.

Comment: yeah @tadman. When I do that, I tend to make it very very clear: `for (;;) /*void*/;` or `for (;;) { /*void*/ }`